# Is there any logical flaw in the arguments in this story between a professor and a student on the problem science has with God?

Tags: logic

I found the following story on this [site](http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-31622.html)

> An atheist professor of philosophy speaks to his class on the problem
>   science has with God, The Almighty.
>
> He asks one of his new students to stand and.....
>
> **Prof**: So you believe in God?
>
> **Student**: Absolutely, sir.
>
> **Prof** : Is God good?
>
> **Student**: Sure.
>
> **Prof**: Is God all-powerful?
>
> **Student**: Yes.
>
> **Prof**: My brother died of cancer even though he prayed to God to heal
>   him.
>
> Most of us would attempt to help others who are ill. But God didn't.
>   How is this God good then? Hmm?
>
> (Student is silent.)
>
> **Prof**: You can't answer, can you? Let's start again, young fella. Is
>   God good?
>
> **Student**: Yes.
>
> **Prof**: Is Satan good?
>
> **Student**: No.
>
> **Prof**: Where does Satan come from?
>
> **Student**: From...God...
>
> **Prof**: That's right. Tell me son, is there evil in this world?
>
> **Student**: Yes.
>
> **Prof**: Evil is everywhere, isn't it? And God did make everything.
>   Correct?
>
> **Student**: Yes.
>
> **Prof**: So who created evil?
>
> (Student does not answer.)
>
> **Prof**: Is there sickness? Immorality? Hatred? Ugliness? All these
>   terrible things exist in the world, don't they?
>
> **Student**: Yes, sir.
>
> **Prof**: So, who created them?
>
> (Student has no answer.)
>
> **Prof**: Science says you have 5 senses you use to identify and observe
>   the world around you.
>
> Tell me, son...Have you ever seen God?
>
> **Student**: No, sir.
>
> **Prof**: Tell us if you have ever heard your God?
>
> **Student**:No, sir.
>
> **Prof**: Have you ever felt your God, tasted your God, smelt your God?
>   Have you ever had any sensory perception of God for that matter?
>
> **Student**: No, sir. I'm afraid I haven't.
>
> **Prof**: Yet you still believe in Him?
>
> **Student**:Yes.
>
> **Prof**: According to empirical, testable, demonstrable protocol, science
>   says your GOD doesn't exist.
>
> What do you say to that, son?
>
> **Student**: Nothing. I only have my faith.
>
> **Prof**: Yes. Faith. And that is the problem science has.
>
> **Student**: Professor, is there such a thing as heat?
>
> **Prof**: Yes.
>
> **Student**: And is there such a thing as cold?
>
> **Prof**: Yes.
>
> **Student**: No sir. There isn't.
>
> (The lecture theatre becomes very quiet with this turn of events.)
>
> **Student** : Sir, you can have lots of heat, even more heat, superheat,
>   mega heat, white heat, a little heat or no heat. But we don't have
>   anything called cold. We can hit 458 degrees below zero which is no
>   heat, but we can't go any further after that.
>
> There is no such thing as cold . Cold is only a word we use to
>   describe the absence of heat
>
> We cannot measure cold. Heat is energy . Cold is not the opposite of
>   heat, sir, just the absence of it .
>
> (There is pin-drop silence in the lecture theatre.)
>
> **Student**: What about darkness, Professor? Is there such a thing as
>   darkness?
>
> **Prof**: Yes. What is night if there isn't darkness?
>
> **Student** : You're wrong again, sir. Darkness is the absence of
>   something. You can have low light, normal light, bright light,
>   flashing light....But if you have no light constantly, you have
>   nothing and it's called darkness, isn't it? In reality, darkness
>   isn't. If it were you would be able to make darkness darker, wouldn't
>   you?
>
> **Prof**: So what is the point you are making, young man?
>
> **Student**: Sir, my point is your philosophical premise is flawed.
>
> **Prof**: Flawed? Can you explain how?
>
> Student: Sir, you are working on the premise of duality. You argue
>   there is life and then there is death, a good God and a bad God. You
>   are viewing the concept of God as something finite, something we can
>   measure. Sir, science can't even explain a thought. It uses
>   electricity and magnetism, but has never seen, much less fully
>   understood either one.To view death as the opposite of life is to be
>   ignorant of the fact that death cannot exist as a substantive thing.
>   Death is not the opposite of life: just the absence of it.
>
> Now tell me, Professor.Do you teach your students that they evolved
>   from a monkey?
>
> **Prof**: If you are referring to the natural evolutionary process, yes,
>   of course, I do.
>
> **Student**: Have you ever observed evolution with your own eyes, sir?
>
> (The Professor shakes his head with a smile, beginning to realize
>   where the argument is going.)
>
> **Student**: Since no one has ever observed the process of evolution at
>   work and cannot even prove that this process is an on-going endeavor,
>   are you not teaching your opinion, sir? Are you not a scientist but a
>   preacher? (The class is in uproar.)
>
> **Student**: Is there anyone in the class who has ever seen the
>   Professor's brain?
>
> (The class breaks out into laughter.)
>
> **Student** : Is there anyone here who has ever heard the Professor's
>   brain, felt it, touched or smelt it? No one appears to have done so.
>   So, according to the established rules of empirical, stable,
>   demonstrable protocol, science says that you have no brain,sir.
>
> With all due respect, sir, how do we then trust your lectures, sir?
>
> (The room is silent. The professor stares at the student, his face
>   unfathomable.)
>
> **Prof**: I guess you'll have to take them on faith, son.
>
> **Student**: That is it sir... The link between man & god is FAITH . That
>   is all that keeps things moving & alive.

Are there any logical flaws in the student's or teacher's arguments?

Comment: I've never seen such a science professor so ignorant of basic science, nor such a religious person so ignorant of his belief. Arguments between two idiots proves nothing about science nor religion.

Comment: This is really long...

Answer (score 4):

The critical flaw comes in the middle, with a reduction of "science" to "what can be empirically observed directly", and at the end, with the substitution of "faith" for "knowledge of that which is not directly observed."

Clearly, much of our understanding of the world comes from direct observation, but much also comes from such means as inference and analogy, and the testimony of reliable authorities (who in turn rely on direct perception, inference, and analogy, etc.)

Like most amateur apologetics, this piece relies on a combination of straw men and sloppy definitions.

Note: I'm ignoring the specifically theological parts of the argument, as those are best treated on other StackExchange sites.

Comment: Also, I would like to point out the statement "According to empirical, testable, demonstrable protocol, science says your GOD doesn't exist." Testable encompasses much more than touch, feel, see, smell etc.

Comment: There are further problems with that statement, among them that science doesn't follow a rigid protocol; and that science doesn't dictate that gods don't exist, so much as there is no predictive motive for postulating the existence of any gods. (Laplace, for instance, didn't disprove the existence of God, though he did observe that he had no need to consider that hypothesis.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement that no one has ever oserved evolution a work is just plain wrong. In fact, researchers do this at a regular basis to test how individuals inherit their parent's characteristics, albeit mostly on animals such as flies or mice.

However evolution doesn't just work between generations but also during an individual's lifelife. This is called epigenetics. Domesticated pigs, for example, will revert to being more boar like (with elongated, straight skulls and furry hide) if released into the wild in just a few years. This is because of recessive genes dormant in the pig's DNA. A lot of creatures have genes from past "forms" still in their DNA just waiting for their environment to trigger them. Chickens still have teeth genes that can be reactivated (a legacy from their reptilian heritage)...

The whole god/science debate is also pretty lame in itself. People of faith say that they rely on faith but nevertheless use the same science they disbelieve to prove to atheists that God exists.

The whole point to faith is to believe in the absence of proof, otherwise it would not be faith but knowledge.

Science doesn't deal with faith but with proof and theories, always revising the theory in light of new evidence. If a scientist ever says "I will stick to my 'knowledge' of science even if new evidence surfaces" then we're no longer talking about science but about some kind of science inspired religion...